# SQL Query to find duplicates in one table but only if at least one of the duplicates has an appointment which is in a different table

Tags: sql

Thanks to this great community I've already had a huge success in my data searching.  Using:

```
select patient.last, patient.first, patient.birth, count(*)
from patient
group by patient.last, patient.first, patient.birth
having count(*) > 1
```

It listed out all my duplicate values!  Now, I'd like to take this a step farther so that I can list ONLY those duplicates that have an appointment on a certain day.  There are several issues I'm running into though.

First only one of the two duplicates will have an appointment.
Second the appointment date is stored on a different table (fun enough called APPT)

I tried:

```
select appt.date
from appt
where appt.date=curdate()+1
union
select patient.last, patient.first, patient.birth, count(*)
from patient
group by patient.last, patient.first, patient.birth
having count(*) > 1
```

But this caused an error about columns not matching.  I couldn't figure out how to innerjoin because when I selected appt.date it affected the group by.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: What's the relation between `appt` and `patient`? Can you share their structures?

Comment: My current result is 10,000 patients who have a duplicate value, which is what I wanted.  The results I want is to narrow down to a group of that 10,000 who have an exam on a certain day...like tomorrow...so I can merge those accounts before the patient comes in.

Comment: Which value is doublicate?

Comment: patient.first, patient.last, patient.birth are the duplicate values.  For example, in my system I will have two "John"  "Smith"  "6/26/1980"...one of those two john smiths will have an appointment tomorrow, one will not.  I want to see a list of duplicate values where they are scheduled for an appointment tomorrow (or a date I specify but that is besides the point of this conversation)

Comment: Which column links the 2 tables?

Comment: there is a patunique column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume (as you say in the comment) there is a column `patunique` in the table `patient` which is the primary key and also in the table `appt` which refernces the column in the table `patient`.
So use EXISTS twice to identify the rows that meet the conditions:

```
select p.last, p.first, p.birth, count(*) counter
from patient p
where 
  exists (select 1 from patient where patunique <> p.patunique and last = p.last and first = p.first and birth = p.birth)
  and 
  exists (select 1 from appt where patunique = p.patunique and date = curdate() + 1)
group by p.last, p.first, p.birth
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select p.last, p.first, p.birth, count(*)
from patient p
where exists (select 1
              from appt a
              where a.date = curdate() and
                    a.patunique = p.patunique
             )
group by p.last, p.first, p.birth
having count(*) > 1;
```

Note:  You need a way to identify the patient for each appointment.  This assumes a column such as `patunique` which provides the link.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong as it's returning no values.  I setup the above and changed patient_id to patunique (which is the patient_id equivalent in the database).     This is what I used (and I confirmed I have at least 1 duplicate on the date)
```
select p.last, p.first, p.birth, count(*)
from patient p
where exists (select 1
              from appt a
              where a.date = curdate() and
                    a.patient_id = p.patient_id
             )
group by p.last, p.first, p.birth
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: @joshuaesa . . . It is not clear why this would not work.  It directly incorporates the logic that you describe.  And it does so more simply than the other answer.